# How to apply a For Each loop to paragraphs past a certain bookmark or page number?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to delete blank pages in my Word document. Because of the issues this process raises in terms of screwing up the document's formatting I have opted to only apply this deletion at the end of the document (past a certain bookmark to be exact). The (little too aggressive) deletion code itself:

```
For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    If Len(para.Range.Text) <= 1 Then
        para.Range.Delete
    End If
Next para
```

At the moment I have tried:

```
Dim iPage As Long
cursor.Goto What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:=("Appendix")
iPage = cursor.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
```

Where iPage gets the page number of the Selection when it has gone to my bookmark "Appendix."

**My question is, how do I apply this deletion only to the paragraphs past this point?**

Comment: What do you mean by *"apply this page number"*?

Comment: sorry, typo. ammended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
Dim para As Paragraph
With ThisDocument
    For Each para In .Range(.Bookmarks("Appendix").End, .Range.End).Paragraphs
        If Len(para.Range.Text) <= 1 Then para.Range.Delete
    Next
End With
```

Comment: Works with a slight modification.

I exchanged ThisDocument for objWord.ActiveDocument.
Thanks for your help, I learnt a few new things about the VB syntax!